# How to deal with a regression where a subset of data has more target information

Tags: regression, machine-learning, ensemble-learning, stacking

I am regressing the hire price of venues. I have a dataset with lots of venues containing information on each venue. Each row is one venue and an associated price and an associated day of week from Monday to Sunday. So each venue has 7 rows, one for each price on each day of the week.

I have found that for the majority of the data (~70%, 1000 venues) that the price does not vary on different week days i.e. Venue X has a hire price of £1000 on all week days Monday to Sunday. This is likely because the venue couldnt be bothered to provide the granular week day variation and instead provided a single value, perhaps an average or minimum hire price.

So, basically, ideally I would like to capture the variation of price per week day, but this is only actually available in about 30% (~300) rows of the data.

How can I approach this problem to incorporate the weekly variation?

I have had the following ideas:

- Split data according to whether the prices vary per weekday. Create 2 separate models from the 2 datasets and test them on their associated data. The downside here is that that the varying model will use far fewer observations for training.
- Create a model from just the non-varying per weekday data, then use the varying data to calculate the average % increase in price on different weekdays and then add this to the model i.e. do the prediction then add 10% for a monday, and I can test this on the varying data and see if it gets a good score. The downside here is that if weekday variation depends on say the location of a venue, then it wont be captured by my model.
- Stacking the first bullet point above's models together -> I know very little about stacking and I dont understand how they could be stacked together if they were trained on different data...